# Which Phenols give the colours blue, green or violet in the neutral FeCl3 test?

Tags: phenols

I have read about the neutral FeCl3 test for Phenols, where a positive test is indicated by the colour of the solution which ranges from green to blue to violet. But which specific derivatives of phenol give a specific colour? Or is it random?

Answer (score 5):

The color of the solution will depend on what substituent is attached to phenol. The following is an excerpt from an e-book:

> **Ferric Chloride Test:** To 2 ml aqueous or alcoholic solution of compound, add 5-6 drops of freshly prepared neutral ferric chloride solution. Colored complexes of phenols are produced
>
> \begin{array}{c|c}
> \mathbf{Compounds} & \mathbf{Color} \\\hline
> \text{phenol, resorcinol, o-cresol, p-cresol} & \text{Violet or blue}\\
> \text{catechol} & \text{Green} \\
> \text{hydroquinone} & \text{Violet or transient blue which changes to yellow on excess addition of FeCl3}\\
> \text{pyrogallol} & \text{Blue rapidly changing to red}\end{array}
>
> Aqueous solution of 1 and 2-naphthol however do not give any characteristic coloration but their alcoholic solution give violet-blue and green coloration respectively due to formation of dinaphthols.

Ref.: *Systematic Lab Experiments in Organic Chemistry* by Arun Sethi, New Age International, **2006**